# Meteor.user with Additional Fields on Client

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

In Meteor, one can add additional fields to the root-level of the new user document like so:

```js
// See: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#adding-fields-on-registration
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => 
  // Add custom field to user document...
  user.customField = "custom data";

  return user;
});
```

On the client, one can retrieve some data about the current user like so:

```js
// { _id: "...", emails: [...] }
Meteor.user()
```

By default, the `customField` does not exist on the returned user. How can one retrieve that additional field via the `Meteor.user()` call such that we get `{ _id: "...", emails: [...], customField: "..." }`? At present, the documentation on [publishing custom data](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#publish-custom-data) appears to suggest publishing an additional collection. This is undesired for reasons of overhead in code and traffic. Can one override the default fields for `Meteor.user()` calls to provide additional fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of solutions that you can use to solve this.

1. Null Publication

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  if (this.userId !== null) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, { fields: { customField: 1 } });
  } else {
    return this.ready();
  }
}, { is_auto: true });
```

This will give you the desired result but will also result in an additional database lookup.. While this is don't by _id and is extremely efficient, I still find this to be an unnecessary overhead.

2.Updating the fields the Meteor publishes for the user by default.

```
Accounts._defaultPublishFields.projection = { customField: 1, ...Accounts._defaultPublishFields.projection };
```

This has to be ran **outside** of any `Meteor.startup` blocks. If ran within one, this will not work. This method will not result in extra calls to your database and is my preferred method of accomplishing this.

Comment: The second option, `Accounts._defaultPublishFields`, looks to be exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately I do not see this option, it is `undefined` for me. What version(s) are you on (Meteor, Accounts, etc.?)

Comment: After upgrading to Meteor 2.0 (I had a prompt to run `meteor update` in the CLI for this), I found the `Accounts._defaultPublishFields` property which allowed me to add the customField to the projection. This works like a charm for users on a sufficient version!

Comment: This might be marginally more efficient, but if you are building a production system, I would caution against using underscored fields. They are, after all, marked as private for a reason. They may break at any time and you won't even be warned about it in the breaking changes notices that come with meteor updates.

Comment: As stated, this is considered a private field and it could change. This personally wouldn't stop me from using this method. Rather, I would write a test to make sure that this operates as expected. While this is only a marginal gain, those marginal gains can add up to a big difference if you are serving 10s of thousands of users.

Comment: @ChristianFritz - a fair point in regards to safety, but there is an easy mitigation in the form of tests and I don’t think wasting network calls is a laughing matter. Besides, it’s JavaScript so danger is inherent in every invocation thanks to the language’s dynamism.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually misunderstanding the documentation. It is not suggesting to populate and publish a separate collection, just a separate publication. That's different. You can have multiple publications/subscriptions that all feed the same collection. So all you need to do is:

Server:

```js
Meteor.publish('my-custom-user-data', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {customField: 1}});
});
```

Client:

```js
Meteor.subscribe('my-custom-user-data');
```

Comment: This does get the field from server to client. However this works by virtue of Meteor merging the initial published document with the result of the document from this second publication which results in two queries, no? This is side-stepping the intent of the question a bit.

Comment: What would be more accurate to say about the documentation, if not that “I am publishing an additional collection” then “I am publishing an additional stream of database changes?” Does this make more accurate?